# cannot connect to directory in bitbucket pipeline

Tags: bitbucket, pipeline

I've read that you can specify in your yml configuration the directory so it does not build in the root but rather in `/sites/mywebsitename`.

The config until the error:

```
image: php:7.4

pipelines:
 branches:
   master:
     - step:
         name: Deploy to production
         deployment: production
         script:
           - cd sites
```

The error:

```
No such file or directory
```

Any comment or advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your bitbucket-pipeline.yml was exactly as you shared and you posted complete, there's one missing line that needs to have the "pipe" listed there, under "script". As reference, please visit this thread:

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Pipeline-fails-with-No-such-file-or-directory/qaq-p/1069160

I hope it is useful for you.